# Azure Multifactor Authentication how to do Passcode Verification on sign in page

Tags: azure, authentication, one-time-password

I want to integrate `Multi-Factor Authentication` into my custom built, Azure Hosted website.

I want the user to get an `OTP (One Time Password) over SMS` and then enter that OTP on the Sign-in page.

How am I supposed to verify the OTP entered by the user on Sign-in page? I was unable to find anything related to that in the `SDK` and online documentation.

`SDK` documentation on `MSDN` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn422962.aspx tells us that:

"Text messages. Windows `Azure Multi-Factor Authentication` can send an SMS text message with a one-time passcode to any mobile phone. To complete the sign-in process, the user is prompted to reply with the passcode or passcode and PIN, or to enter the passcode on an application sign-in screen."

but unfortunately it doesn't tell how the sent passcode is verified, either via the `SDK` itself or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

It's really confusing coz one would think the received token needs to be entered on the comp, but apparently the SMS needs to be replied to the SMS sender. All the docs on the net shows differently, they all show some second login screen for the token to be entered:

http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/services/its/servicessupport/networkservices/vpn/itsvpn/

But no, it's not quite how it works with Azure.

For whatever reason SMS didn't work for me. I did receive the SMSes but even after I replied to the sender number, it still wouldn't authenticate me. Also, it'd have increased the costs even further so I just sticked with the automated phone call.

Now I use it to authenticate VPN users on our Cisco ASA firewall. The authentication process goes like this:

1. user clicks on connect in the VPN client
2. user enters user + password, then clicks login, now the client is waiting for a response
3. credentials are sent to ASA, which asks the Multi-Factor Authentication Server if they're ok
4. the MFAS verifies that they're ok so it tells Azure to call the user's phone number
5. user receives call, presses the # key (that's the "standard" method, there's also a PIN method), then Azure hangs up the call and tells the MFAS that it can proceed
6. MFAS tells the ASA that the user's authenticated
7. client exits the waiting state and logs in